# Scheduled task execution issue in drupal's cron

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7, cron

I have module, called parser2, which does parsing from html pages. Everything works perfectly, except cron schedule. It just doesnt add my task to cron tasks, and in logs, i see there are 0 scheduled tasks, everytime cron runs. The next issue, if i manually start cron few times, after i'm getting white screen of death, and the only 1 thing that helps me, its delete parser2 tables from DB, and from system.table, and then run update.php.
Here is the code that should be doing all this work, but i cant understand where is error here

```
 function parser_cron_queue_info() {
    $info = array();
    $info['get_parser_weather'] = array(
    'worker callback' => 'parser_weather',
    'time' => 10,      
  );
    $query = db_select('parser_jobs', 'pn')
    ->fields('pn', array('id','time_run_in_crone'))
    ->condition('run_in_crone', 1)
    ->execute();
    foreach ($query as $job){
        $info['get_parser_weather_'.$job->id] = array(
        'worker callback' => 'parser_weather',
        'time' => $job->time_run_in_crone,      
   };
  }
  return $info;
}


function parser_cron() {

  $query = db_select('parser_jobs', 'pn')
    ->fields('pn', array('id','time_run_in_crone'))
    ->condition('run_in_crone', 1)
    ->execute();
  foreach ($query as $job){
    $queue = DrupalQueue::get('get_parser_weather_'.$job->id);
    $queue->createItem($job->id);
  }


}

function  parser_weather($job_id){

    $job = parser_job_load($job_id);
   _parser_url_delete_all();
   _parser_url_add($job->start_url);
   while (_parser_url_get_not_parsed())
   {
      parser_parse2($job);
    };
}
```

Comment: Probably maybe there is another way to force this task run on cron runs?

Comment: Don't see anything immediately wrong, have you tried walking through this with xdebug triggering the code manually, perhaps using a simple menu callback that points to the cron function?

Comment: The problem, is that in logs there are messages about cron run, and i've added in common.inc line to show if my module runs aswell. So it does, but somewhy module doesnt start to parse as intended. More then if i trying to run cron manually from drupal admin section, after few runs im getting white screen of death, and some mysql error in apache log.

Comment: *"some mysql error in apache log"* - that's not very specific...

Comment: most likely this issue caused by php APC, will check tomorrow

Comment: Did you clear the cache? Whenever I do anything like this I use drush: `drush cc all`.

Comment: Well issue was caused my APC, dont know why, but after i disabled apc for my project, everything went fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try getting the cron command the code is generating and then run it in you command line to make sure it is correct also double check if the user your script is running has permission to add new task.